# Use XPath to found text row in query json

Tags: json, xpath

To introduce me : I'm not developer, and I want to control the element is present in my json.

I have this type of json, and i want to control for exemple that "id = display-page" but I don't know how can I structure of my xpath to found it

`"text": "{\"id\":\"display-page\",\"recoVideo_hasRecoLoaded\":\"\",\"recovideo_requiredEngine\":\"tp1top\",\"recovideo_executedEngine\":\"tp1top\",\"recovideo_fallbackEngine\":\"\",\"recovideo_abtestEngine\":\"\",\"recovideo_recoVideoId\":\"top-video-web-desktop-windows-PERSONA_DEFAULT\"`

I try something like *$..request.text.[?(@.name =='id')].value.display-page*
but it doesn't work :(

Someone to help me ?

Thanks !
Antoine

Comment: Xpath is for XML. You can use `jq` utility to query json.

Comment: It is not clear which version or extension of XPath you are trying to use, XPath 3.1 can process JSON as XDM maps and array with the lookup operator `?`. But a dot operator `request.text` or `value.display-page` doesn't look like XPath, not even 3.1. The structure of your input JSON is also not clear, do you have a property named `text` which has a string value with escaped JSON?